# Merge not-blank result fields by sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, distinct

Let's supose I have a complicated query, that takes data from lots of table.

```
    SELECT
    DISTINCT
        table1.hash, 
        table2.field1,
        table3.field1,
        table4.field1, 
...
...
...
    FROM table1
    inner JOIN table2
    ON table1.hash=device_model.hash 
        and table1.date = table2.date 
        and table1.time = table2.time

...
...
...
    inner JOIN table_n-1
    ON table1.hash=table_n-1.hash 
        and table1.date = table_n-1.date 
        and table1.time = table_n-1.time
    left JOIN table_n
    ON table1.hash=table_n.hash 
        and table1.date = table_n.date 
        and table1.time = table_n.time
...
...
...
    ORDER BY table1.date
```

Thanks to "DISTINCT" operator I've got result of three rows like

```
+---------+----------+------------+
|value1   |Null      | value3     |
+---------+----------+------------+ 
|value1   |Null      | Null       |
+---------+----------+------------+ 
|value1   |value2    | null       |
+---------+----------+------------+ 
|value1   |Null      | value3     |
+---------+----------+------------+
```

So I have at least one Null in each row.
How can I merge the result of selection in one row to have all data?
I'd like to see smth like:

```
+---------+----------+------------+ 
|value1   |value2    | value3     |
+---------+----------+------------+
```

Obviously that value3 from first row is equal to value3 from last row.
So, result rows is different just by Null's.

Comment: GROUP BY value1Field before ORDER

Comment: If you do `GROUP BY` on only the first column, you'll still get duplicate results. Maybe `GROUP BY` on all the columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for is a matter of grouping and using the `max` aggregate function. Suppose you have this table (your query is huge to paste in here :):

```
+---------+---------+----------+------------+
|hash     |field1   |field2    | field3     |
+---------+---------+----------+------------+
|hash01   |value1   |Null      | value3     |
|hash01   |value1   |Null      | Null       |
|hash01   |value1   |value2    | null       |
|hash01   |value1   |Null      | value3     |
+---------+---------+----------+------------+
```

You can group by the hash column and apply a `max` on the rest. That way `value2` would be preferred over `null` in field2 and `value3` would be again preferred over `null` in field3. In this example there are 2 `value3` for the same hash. So the `max` function will still work. If there are 2 different values for the same hash in the same column then you should clarify what you want to do with them, as only one can be chosen in the result (based on your example).

So the query for the above result would be something like:

```
select hash, max(field1) as field1, max(field2) as field2, max(field3) as field3
group by hash
```

Applying this to your example, would most likely mean that you have to remove the `distinct` clause and select/grouping the results in the same way I did in the simplified example    .